# Tracking records with different specifications

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I setup a form that allows a user to click on a part to see the part’s specifications (on another form) when the specification form is different depending on the part selected? For example. I have three parts in an assembly. Each of those parts is different. I.e amplifier, mixer etc... but I want to see their unique test data.  A better analogy might be how do I see the stats for athletes that participate in different events when they are all part of the same team? A runner has different stats then a long jumper. I just want to have a form that lists all atheletes on a team but shows individual stats when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how your database is structured.

I would probably use a subform control I can change on the `Form_Current` event.

Note that this choice reflects my preferred choice in table structure: one common table listing common properties, and one table per category listing specific properties for that category.

E.g.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Select Case txtCategoryControl
        Case "amplifier"
            mySubformControl.SourceObject = "AmplifierSubform"
        Case "mixer"
            mySubformControl.SourceObject = "MixerSubform"
        Case Else
            mySubformControl.SourceObject = ""
    End Select
Exit Sub
```